# An isosceles trapezoid with legs of length $13$ has no horizontal or vertical sides. Determine possible equations for bounding lines.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The legs of an isosceles trapezoid each have a length of $13$. None of the sides of the trapezoid are horizontal nor vertical. Determine equations for each of the four lines whose intersections could be the vertices of the trapezoid.

From the comments:

> Tried graphing out with random coordinates that would give me the length one of the legs with (0,0) as one of the coordinates

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this guidelines to improve your question https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The description allows the trapezoid to be anywhere and almost any orientation in the (x,y) plane.  Also the lengths of the other two sides are not specified.  There is no one solution..

Comment: Tried graphing out with random coordinates that would give me the length one of the legs with (0,0) as one of the coordinates

Comment: It is worth knowing that $5^2+12^2=13^2$.  So three of the lines could be $y=x$ and $y=\frac{12}{5}x$ and $y=x+7$ since $7=12-5$.  Can you find a fourth?

Comment: [Please read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28072/104041), @AhmadBazzi.